# Compress .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, compression, minify

I've got a htaccess file which contains over 3,000 lines mainly thanks to 301 redirects I have setup from my old ecommerce site. The file is 323kb in size and I'm worried it's going to be a burden for load times and therefore conversions.

Is there anything available that can compress (minify?) the file into a smaller size or someone offer a better idea to handle the 301 redirects?

Comment: Thanks for the replies but there is pattern matching to the domains that can be done I don't think. There is no logical comparison between the old urls and the new ones.

RedirectMatch 301 /acatalog/1000_Mile_Ultimate_Tactel_Ladies_Walking_Socks.html /1000-mile-ultimate-tactel.html
RedirectMatch 301 /acatalog/1000_Mile_Ultimate_Tactel_Men_s_Walking_Sock.html /1000-mile-ultimate-tactel.html
RedirectMatch 301 /acatalog/12_240_Volt_Mains_Adaptor.html /campingaz-12-240-volt-mains-adaptor.html

Answer (score 1):

If the redirects are simple redirects i.e. `url1` to `url2`, no regex etc, AND you have access to httpd.conf, then you could use a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/rewritemap.html#txt) for all the redirects and possibly have just 1 rule in your .htaccess to handle these.

From the RewriteMap documentation

> The looked-up keys are cached by httpd until the mtime (modified time) of the mapfile changes, or the httpd server is restarted. This ensures better performance on maps that are called by many requests.

Comment: I suspect that if Gavin had access to the apache root or vhost config then he wouldn't be using `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 1):

Can you specify some regular expressions to group / match all of these redirects?  This then offers two options for doing this:

- The first is to use a (hopefully smaller) set of `RewriteRule` statements using the `[R=301]` flag.
- The second is to move this redirection into a redirector script where you use, say, PHP logic to decode the legacy ecommerce URI into its current format then issue a response with and 301/302 status and Location: pointing to the current URI.  This would also need you to do a catch-all rewrite of the legacy ecommerce URIs to this redirector script, e.g.

  ```
  RewriteRule ^(product/.*) rewriter.php?uri=$1  [QSA,L]
  ```

Without some examples, I can't give a more specific reply. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some of these cases before, most of the times you can replace the redirect statments with RewriteRules. For example, if your URL's went from:

```
http://shop.example.com/shop/category/product-id.html
```

To this:

```
http://shop.example.com/category/product-id.html
```

You can fetch it with a rewrite like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/shop/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ /$1/$2.html [L, R=301]
```

This will still result in a 301 redirect, so crawlers will still know it's a permanent move.